# Limit superior and inferior when one part diverges

Tags: calculus, limits, limsup-and-liminf

How can I find the limit superior and inferior of given sequence:
$x_n = (1 + \frac{1}{2n})\cos{\frac{n\pi }{3}}$
as $ n \in \mathbb N $

I did the following: since $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1 + \frac{1}{2n}) = 1$ and the second term' limit oscillates between -1 and 1, I decided that the supremum should be $1$ and infimum should be $-1$.
But this is an incorrect answer.

What I do wrong? Thank you.

**UPD:**
It is a task from the online-courses site and there is an automatic answer checking system. So, as I said in my question, answer $-1$ and $1$ not passed and there is no explanation why.

I believe there should be used Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem to find all possible convergent subsequences, and then find limits for each of them...

Comment: It does not look wrong to me; all values are close to one of $-1,-\frac12,\frac12,1$, and get arbitrarily close as $n$ increases

Comment: Henry, unfortunately, the answer $-1 \frac{-1}{2} \frac12 1$ is wrong as well as the answer $-1 1$. I edited my question so there could be new helpful information.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{2n}) = 1$ and $0 \le |\cos(x)| \le 1$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$, so
$$\limsup_n \,(1+\frac{1}{2n}) = 1 \text{ and } 
\limsup_n \, \left|\cos{\frac{n\pi }{3}} \right| \le 1.$$
Using [$\limsup ( a_n b_n ) \leqslant \limsup a_n \limsup b_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113121/290189) (with $a_n = 1 + \frac{1}{2n}$ and $b_n = |\cos\frac{n\pi}{3}|$), we have
$$\limsup_n \, (1 + \frac{1}{2n}) \left|\cos{\frac{n\pi }{3}} \right| \le 1,$$
so
$$-1 \le -\limsup_n \, (1 + \frac{1}{2n}) \left|\cos{\frac{n\pi }{3}} \right| \le \liminf_n\, (1 + \frac{1}{2n}) \cos{\frac{n\pi }{3}}.$$

(Recall that $\liminf_n a_n$ can be equivalently defined as the minimum possible limit of subsequence $(a_{n_k})_k$, which is bounded below by $(-|a_{n_k}|)_k$.)

- $n = 6k + 3$: $x_n = (1 + \frac{1}{12k + 6})(-1) \to -1$ as $k \to \infty$.
- $n = 6k$: $x_n = (1 + \frac{1}{12k})(1) \to 1$ as $k \to \infty$.

This shows that $\limsup_n x_n = 1$ and $\liminf_n x_n = -1$.

---

**(Edit in response to OP's update)**

OP has appealed to his online system that we have *no* access to to conclude that my answer is wrong.

Here, I'm going to prove that why
$$\limsup_n \,x_n < 1+\epsilon \quad \forall \epsilon > 0.$$
In other words, wny number $1 + \epsilon$ strictly greater than $1$ *can't* be a limit of any subsequence of $(x_n)_n$.  With the example subsequence $n = 6k$ in the last part of my original answer, this would show that $\limsup_n x_n = 1$.

The idea is simple: $\require{cancel}$
$$x_n = \underbrace{\left( \color{red}{1+\frac{1}{2n}} \right)}_{\to 1} \; \xcancel{\color{blue}{\cos{\frac{n\pi }{3}}}}.$$

[image: Wiki's picture]
Source: Wikipedia's page on $\limsup$ in French

To make it rigorous, for any $\epsilon > 0$, take $N = \left\lceil \dfrac{1}{\epsilon} \right\rceil$.  For all $n \ge N$,
$$\left( 1 + \dfrac{1}{2n} \right) \cos{\frac{n\pi }{3}} \le \left( 1 + \dfrac{1}{2n} \right) \, (1) \le 1 + \dfrac12\:\epsilon < 1 + \epsilon,$$
which violates the later part of (1) in the proposition in [an older question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/47814/290189): the above inequality shows that $x_n \le 1 + \dfrac\epsilon2$ eventually, instead of $x_n > (1 + \epsilon) - \dfrac\epsilon2$ frequently.

---

A shorter alternative solution: use the following computation rule (Proposition 2.4 from [this note](http://people.math.aau.dk/~cornean/analyse2_F14/limsup-liminf.pdf)).

> Let $(a_n)_n$ and $(b_n)_n$ be two bounded real sequences such that $b_n$ converges to $b \ge 0$.  Then
>   \begin{align}
> \limsup_n\, a_nb_n &= b \limsup_n\, a_n \text{ and } \\
> \liminf_n\, a_nb_n &= b \liminf_n\, a_n.
> \end{align}

Apply this rule with $a_n = \cos\dfrac{n\pi}{3}$ and $b_n = 1 + \dfrac{1}{2n}$ to get the same conclusion.

Comment: Thank you, but the answer $-1$ and $1$ is wrong. I edited my question, can you look at this again, maybe it will be helpful?

Comment: @Alex I'm sorry to say that your edit doesn't make any difference to the community. This is *Math*.SE, and we exchange *maths*. We deal with maths issues, not technical ones. You may question my arguments here, but nobody can help with your system.  Since we have *no* access to your system, we *can't* debug your system. If you bother to visit GitHub, where many softwares are hosted, you'll be astonished by the amount of issues/errors and pull requests of *any* popular project. Btw, a math book may contain errors, as one can see from the errata.

Comment: Sorry, you probably misunderstood me. The platform I was talking about is stepik site. I don't think we should try to find bugs in their platform. I just wanted to say that this answer is incorrect there and I only have some hint (I wrote it at the end of my edit): "I believe there should be used Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem to find all possible convergent subsequences, and then find limits for each of them"

Comment: @Alex Why's the *mathematical* reason that you think my answer is incorrect?

Comment: if I'd knew it, I wouldn't ask my question here. Again and again: my update contains 2 parts. In the first one, I said that this answer is incorrect and explained why (!) I don't know why this answer is incorrect. Please, notice the second part of my edit: there are a hint from course teacher that Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem should be used to find all existing convergent subsequences of the sequence given, and then find limits for each of them. Thank you.

Comment: What can be seen in your "explanation" is just an appeal to an online system that we don't have access to.  The Bolzano-Weiertrass theorem isn't needed here.  Just reason from the basics will do: 1. limsup as the maximum possible limit of a subsequent 2. ordinary limit, if it's defined, is just limsup/liminf 3.

Comment: @Alex I've [edit]ed my answer in response to your update. You may invoke the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem to say something about the liminf and limsup of $\cos(\cdots)$ in the alternative approach, but it's fine to draw the conclusion without it.